# Basic Questions about Tense

Tags: difference, sentence-structure, subjunctive, tense

1. What are the differences between these two examples?

- A) Er hat ihm den Wagen zu waschen geholfen.
- B) Er habe ihm den Wagen zu waschen geholfen.

2. and also what are the differences between these two examples?/Why is "waschen" used one time with "zu" and one time without "zu"?

- C) Er hat ihm geholfen, den Wagen zu waschen.
- D) Er hat ihm den Wagen waschen geholfen.

Comment: There are two separate issues here, even if they are both based on the same example. It's helpful to split up questions when possible so they can be answered separately. If you feel the need you can always link the questions as related.

Answer (score 1):

A is the the ordinary perfect tense which I'm confident you're already familiar with. B is the special subjunctive (Konjunktiv I) in the past tense. The main difference is that the subjunctive is used when there is some uncertainty about what is being said. For example it may be something someone else said or thought: *Sie sagte, er habe ihm geholfen, den Wagen zu waschen.* English does not really have this form, so both sentences are the same when translated into English. (English does have a special subjunctive, but it's not used the same way. There is also a general subjunctive, Konjunktiv II, but that's a topic for another question.) Bruce Duncan has a [page on the special subjunctive](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivI.html) with more information.

There is actually a third issue here, namely the placement of the infinitive clause *den Wagen zu waschen*. It's in the middle if the sentence (technically the *Mittelfeld* or middle field) in A and B, and after the main clause (technically the *Nachfeld* or back field) in C. Subclauses in general are usually placed either after the non-finite verb (*geholfen* in this case) or before the finite verb (*hat/habe*), with infinitive clauses using *zu* more likely to be placed after the non-finite verb. German word/phrase order is flexible, so I wouldn't say putting it in the middle is actually wrong, but it does seem awkward.

Anyway, C uses an infinitive clause *den Wagen zu waschen*. In an infinitive clause the main verb is in the infinitive (as you might guess), and the subject is implied by the main clause. The *zu* in front of the verb tells you that it is an infinitive clause and not some other type of subclause. (For separable verbs, the *zu* is actually inserted after the prefix, for example *abzugeben*.) The clause itself is an object for the verb in the main clause, and only certain verbs allow this. Besides *helfen*, some other examples are *hoffen*, *leisten*, *trauen* and *versuchen*. I would consider this the normal way of saying someone is "helping to do something". I think D has several grammatical interpretations, but I think the most probable is that *helfen* and *waschen* being combined into a single compound verb *waschen helfen* = "to help wash". This is allowed according [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/helfen#d-1-1-2) except they don't call it a compound and don't mention the perfect tense. German is very free about forming compounds so I prefer this interpretation. So, according to this, D has a single clause with a compound verb, while C has a main clause and a subclause, each with their own verb. I don't think there is a difference in meaning, though there may be differences in how "natural" they sound or degree of formality. Bruce Duncan also has a [page on infinitive clauses](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/WordOrder/Infinitives.html). (In fact, if you're serious about learning the grammar then I'd suggest reading his entire site.)

Comment: ja, der Antwort kann ich 100%ig zustimmen. C und D sind in ihrer Bedeutung identisch.